# Nginx 504 monitoring

Tags: nginx, monitoring, node.js, system-monitoring

I'm using Nginx to reverse proxy a nodejs instance that is currently timing out when an external service attempts to call a specific, secured api endpoint, generating 504 errors.

How can I setup Nginx to notify me (ie. via email) when it serves a 504? Because the api endpoint in question is secured and relies on specific information being passed, a generic monitoring solution won't work.

I'm very surprised I couldn't find any clear information on how to do this after googling for 15 mins.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use Nginx for this. Rather, you use some sort of log processing package to watch the nginx error log for 504s and notify you when it sees one.

[Logstash](http://logstash.net/) is a very popular and very capable log processing package - it can be easily configured to consume messages out of your error log (using the [file input](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.1/inputs/file)), look for a certain error string (using the [grep filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.1/filters/grep)), and then email an alert if it finds a matching line (using the [email output](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.1/outputs/email)).

Comment: thanks EEAA - knew I must have been looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: logwatch/swatch might be usefull tools too if you want a simpler setup than logstash.